# how to handle future Islamic holidays in data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-warehouse

I am building a date dimension table for my data warehouse.  To my knowledge, date dimension tables are special -- they are loaded only once in the EDW's life.  Because they're loaded only once, then they usually have a large date range, which includes dates in the future.

My company is a multinational company.  Because of this, in particular, I need to build a holiday calendar into this table for Islamic holidays.  Because at least Eid al-Fitr requires actual moon sighting for the holiday to begin (which could be delayed due to, say, cloud cover), how can I load all future Islamic holiday dates into this table?  (I'm not sure if other Islamic holidays require lunar sighting as well.)  Is the best practice to load all tentative future holiday dates and to correct them as each holiday nears (because of the lunar sighting requirement)?

Comment: This doesn't deal with rules for Islamic holidays specifically, but could be used as a general resource for creating a calendar table that can be used when loading. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: Why do you want to have holidays in date dimension?  Create a separate table for the holidays. Create a VIEW on top of holidays and date table using join.

Comment: Yes I would load those future holidays into the calendar table and maybe name them so you know they are approximate for the moment. Those types of holidays are the most difficult to deal with because you can't accurately state the beginning or end. The point being you want to use a calendar table for holidays, not your date dimension.

Comment: Actually, I was already planning on using a separate holiday calendar table to store holidays.  Because users of the EDW will not be parameterizing country, then I am planning on denormalizing the holiday table into the date dimension table.  That way, I don't have a snowflake model.  (I will be using the holiday table in a stored proc that loads the date dimension table.)

Comment: My understanding is that the moon sighting can happen anywhere, which means the date on which the holiday starts will be different based on what time zone you are in.  i.e, a sighting in the western hemisphere will signal the holiday, but for the eastern hemisphere it's the next day. My advice is not to attempt to wedge a 7th century ritualistic moon appearance into a computerized algorithm.